# How can i use XPATH in mule for Getting the XML node values?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-module-jpa

```
#[xpath://soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/out:notifications/out:Notification/out:sObject/urn:Summary]
```

I am using the above `XPATH` Code for fetching the XML node values. It's not Working. How can Correct this. But the following code Working fine.

```
<logger message="#[xpath('//*[local-name()=\'Description\']').text]&quot;" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

i want to work on with the 1st XPATH Syntax format How can i do this?
The Following Code is my XML Dummy data.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:out="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" xmlns:urn="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <out:notifications>
         <out:OrganizationId>12345</out:OrganizationId>
         <out:ActionId>999999</out:ActionId>
         <out:SessionId>000000</out:SessionId>
         <out:EnterpriseUrl>ggggggg</out:EnterpriseUrl>
         <out:PartnerUrl>hhhhhhh</out:PartnerUrl>
         <!--1 to 100 repetitions:-->
         <out:Notification>
            <out:Id>iiiiiiii</out:Id>
            <out:sObject>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <urn:fieldsToNull>jjjjjjj</urn:fieldsToNull>
               <urn:Id>789076</urn:Id>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <urn:FirstName>aaaa</urn:FirstName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <urn:LastName>bbbbb</urn:LastName>
            </out:sObject>
         </out:Notification>
      </out:notifications>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, in the first expression you're referring to an element called `Summary` which doesn't exist in your XML.

Now if you want to use namespaces in your xpath expression, you will have to declare them in the global element called namespace-manager:

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="false">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="soapenv" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="out" uri="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" />
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="urn" uri="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" />
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

Using the above and replacing `Summary` with something that does exist, works:

```
<logger level="WARN" message="#[xpath://soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/out:notifications/out:Notification/out:sObject/urn:Id]" />
```